# http access to a specific folder in a full https enabled directory through .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have enforced https access to the www directory and all subdirectories by rewrite rule in .htaccess -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/%$1 [R,L]
```

However, I need http access to one specific folder /specific/folder/ which is under www directory. How can I do that with rewriting rule in .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need one negative `RewriteCond` in your rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/specific/folder/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: Doesn't this still allow https access to the one directory? Such a URL would not get rewritten.

Comment: Since I somehow stupidly didn't quite understand your question, I'll come back later and delete my two useless comments.